# Hash Function SHA-3

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, brute-force-attack, preimage-resistance, sha-3

I would like to discuss the minimum input of hash function to consider strong (e.g Shack128 (SHA-3)). I have a mechanism based on SHA-3, but the input is just 40-bit, some friends told me 40-bit input consider too weak? please, anyone can help me to know what is the minimum input and what kind of attack I need to consider regarding of the input  (e.g. brute force attack, and what else).

Thanks

Comment: Against what do you want to defend? What is the purpose of your hash function? Depending on what you want to do 40 bit could be enough, but that's only for really limited circumstances.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77201/discussion-on-question-by-al-ani-hash-function-sha-3).

Comment: @SEJPM: This question is answered [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59051/555) and related to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59040/555#comment129743_59042); it you fell like merging the three (any direction), my contribution can be to fix the links I made, where I can.

Comment: @fgrieu merging questions has the requirement for the questions to be 99% identical and I just don't see this here. I think it is reasonable though to close this one as a dupe of the second one and further evaluate merging the third into the second. I'll make things work.

Comment: This duplicate-close has been done as a result of the fact that the linked question has answer(s) that effectively and fully address this question, but the _questions_ were not similar enough for a full-on mod-merge.