# Benchmark for SHA-3 (Shake128)

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack, sha-3

I am trying to find the average of hash rate (benchmark) for SHA-3(Shake128) for a normal and supercomputer in order to estimate the brute-force attack which I can get if from ( keyspace / hash rate )...then I found this website:

https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html

I could not understand these tables i.g. (Cycles/byte for 8 bytes) what do they mean by cycles/byte? Is it that hash rate for 8-bytes?

Answer (score 2):

Cycles per byte means the number of CPU cycles that must elapse in order to process a single byte of input *for a specific processor*. A CPU's clock frequency determines how many cycles per second the processor is running at (for example, 2.6 billion per second for a 2.6 GHz processor). Note that this is a rather crude type of benchmark, because the bottleneck may not be waiting for each instruction to retire. Memory access latency, shared resources, etc. can slow things down.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. Well, based on the table "x86; normally amd64; Sandy Bridge (206a7); 2011 Intel Core i3-2310M; 2 x 2100MHz; h6sandy, supercop-20171218" for "Cycles/byte for 8 bytes" shake128 is 540.50 so the hash rate is (540.50*8) right? please let me know if it is wrong. thanks

Comment: Yes, assuming there are no other bottlenecks (like memory access latency) and it is processing 8 byte chunks at a time. Various optimizations may make it more efficient for different sizes, and of course that hash rate is specific to that CPU at the quoted frequency.

Comment: And when they mentioned on the website 8-bytes they mean the output or the input?? like in my situation I have input 40-bits and the output is Shake128

Comment: I imagine 8 bytes is for the input. Different implementations may optimize for different input sizes, for example you might get away with 16- or 32-byte inputs if you are using a system that supports SIMD.

Comment: Okay, well I got confused "I noticed that the hash rate getting less when the messages size increase". For example, shake128 for 8-bytes 540.50 while for 4096-bytes is 25.90.
"

Comment: In addition, the hash rate for core i3 is higher than core i7? As I know core i7 should get better hash rate compare with core i3!!!!

Comment: Are you sure the hash rate is higher, rather than the cycles per bytes being lower? (low cycles per byte is good)

Comment: cycle per byte does not mean hash rate?

Comment: Cycles per byte are the number of CPU cycles it takes to process a byte of the hash. A lower cycle per byte count means a higher hash rate.

Comment: I'm inclined to _merge_ this question (that is, the answer would be moved to the other question) into [the new one by the OP](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59045/23623), @forest do you prefer your answer to be on the newer question (which means you'd have to adapt it to deal with the slightly different question(s) asked which are already here in the comments) or have it stay here?

Comment: @SEJPM I'll probably just delete the answer since it can't complete with the other answers and doesn't add much (in which case this question can be deleted as well, I don't mind if my answer goes with it).